# setInterval in a useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs, setinterval, use-effect, use-state, react-functional-component

so I have a component in which I like to pull data every X seconds, then check the data with the perviously fetched data, and if anything is different then set the data to be rendered. I have it written it like this:

```
    const [data,setData] = useState(undefined);

    const getPaneData = () => {
        axios.get(url)
            .then (res => checkAndUpdateState(res.data))
            .catch(() => setData(null))
    }

    const checkAndUpdateState = (fetchedData) => {
        if (!data){
            setData (fetchedData)
        }
        if (!deep_Compare(data,fetchedData)){
            // this is to test if data is the same or not
            setData (fetchedData)
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const observeChanges = setInterval(() => getPaneData(), 5000)
        return () => clearInterval(observeChanges);
    }, []);
```

my problem is that the data is always undefined although I can see that I get some data back and it i rendered correctly, the first if statement in checkAndUpdateState always triggers. what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the value of `data` on the 2nd interval?

Comment: it is always undefined

Comment: try putting `console.log(fetchedData)` at the top of `checkAndUpdateState` and see what that outputs

Comment: What does `deep_Compare` do?